# Django: How to filter a subset in a querset?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, subset, django-queryset

How can I filter the elements in a subset?

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user                = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    ...

class Bill(models.Model):
    order           = models.ForeignKey(Order, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL))
    billdate        = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    payed           = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...
```

For example:

```
    order = Orders.objects.all()
    order[0].bill_set # Should return only 3 bills
    order[1].bill_set # Should return only 3 bills
    order[2].bill_set # Should return only 3 bills
    order[3].bill_set # Should return only 3 bills
```

will return all Bills. But I just want to get the latest 3 elements, ordererd by billdate. How can I do this?

I want to use the result in Django Rest Framework in my view:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Order

        fields = (
            'id'
            'bill_set'
        )


class AffiliateOrderViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    serializer_class = OrderSerializer


    def get_queryset(self):
        return Order.objects.filter(bill_set__filter_somehow_only_the_last_3_entries_ordered_by_date)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple add atribute in model Order

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    def get_number_of_last_bill(self, number):
        return self.bill_set.order_by("billdate")[:number]
```

And in queryset, call this:

```
order = Orders.objects.all()

order[0].get_number_of_last_bill(3) 
order[1].get_number_of_last_bill(3)
```

in your serializer, you can add field like this:

```
class BillSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Bill

        fields = (
            'id',
            'payed'
        )

class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    number_of_last_bill = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Order

        fields = (
            'id',
            'bill_set',
            'number_of_last_bill',

        )
    def get_number_of_last_bill(self, obj):
        return BillSerializer(obj.get_number_of_last_bill(3), many=True).data
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I use this approach with django rest framework in my OrderSerializer?

Comment: It is not working for me. I get an '<Bill: Bill object (398)> is not JSON serializable' I guess I need a Serializer somehow for the bill.

Comment: im updated my answer, you can add `BillSerializer` for get json response

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this

```
def get_queryset(self):
        return Order.objects.all()[0].bill_set.order_by('billdate')[:3]
```

or you can do this also

```
def get_queryset(self):
    q1 = Order.objects.all()[0].bill_set
    q2 = q1.order_by('billdate')[0:3]
    return q2
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. I think I was not clear enough. I want to return a Order queryset. But the bill_set for all order "objects" should have max 3 entries ordered by date.